# Jenkins and GitHub: WebHooks and SSH

Tags: git, github, jenkins, webhooks

I have couple questions
1> We are using Jenkins for continuous integration. We have installed GitHub plugin and configured for PUSH notification using Web Hook. Everything is working fine so far.
For this configuration to work we had to host Jenkins server on port 80 and keep that port open for outside world so GitHub can send notifications to CI server. But now for security reason we want to lock down the CI server ( AWS) for all other IP addresses. ( except GitHub and our own internal IP addresses)

What IP address does GitHub use to send notifications so we can exclude that from blocking?

2>I have created SSH as per the documentation https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/
I was able to successfully test SSH connection using the recommended steps. However GitHub plugin is not able to pull the code when i use SSH credentials & SSH url. Note that i have created SSH using pass phrase. Will that be an issue?
Here is the error im getting

> git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:mycompany/cr-tpt.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:mycompany/myrepo.git
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:766)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1022)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1053)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
>   Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:mycompany/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
>   stdout:

Comment: GitHub uses IP addresses range 92.30.252.0/22 - https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist/

Comment: well it also says "We highly recommend that you don't white list IPs for Service Hooks."